# Marshalling a map with struct as key

Tags: dictionary, go, struct, key, marshalling

I have a struct where one of the fields is a map with the key being another struct. I am using Go version 16.1 and the map created that way is supposedly supported in this version (albeit unsure when field is a map). Here is the relevant code and test that fails with unsupported type error.

```
package model

import (
    "encoding/json"
    slog "github.com/go-eden/slf4go"
)

type User struct{
    ID       string             `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    FName    string             `json:"fName"`
    MName    string             `json:"mName"`
    LName    string             `json:"lName"`
    Jobs     map[*Job]float64 `json:"jobs,omitempty"`
    Password string             `json:"password"`
    IsAdmin bool                `json:"isAdmin"`

}

func (u *User)IsModel()bool{
    return true
}

func(u * User)ToJSON()string{
    //var jsonUser string;
    b,err := json.Marshal(u)
    if err !=nil {
        slog.Info(err)
        return err.Error()
    }
    return string(b)
}
func (u * User)FromJSON(jsonString string)bool{
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString),u)
    if err != nil{
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

and the struct job is:

```
package model

import "encoding/json"

type Job struct{
    ID string `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Name string `json:"name"`

}

func(j *Job)IsModel()bool{
    return true
}

func(j *Job) ToJSON()string{
    b,err := json.Marshal(j)
    if err !=nil {
        return err.Error()
    }
    return string(b)
}

func(j *Job) FromJSON(jsonString string)bool{
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString),j)
    if err != nil{
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Finally the test that fails is the following (marshalling fails after I add the job to the jobs map):

```
package model

import (
    
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "testing"
)

func TestUser_ToJSON(t *testing.T) {
    user := &User{
        ID:       "",
        FName:    "Mike",
        MName:    "",
        LName:    "Clovis",
        Jobs:     make(map[*Job]float64),
        Password: "xyz",
        IsAdmin: true,
    }
    newUser := &User{}
    fmt.Println(user.ToJSON())
    job := &Job{
        ID:   "1",
        Name: "Cashier",
    }
    user.Jobs[job] = 12.99
    fmt.Println("User as json")
    fmt.Println(user.ToJSON())
    newUser.FromJSON(user.ToJSON())
    fmt.Println(newUser)
    if reflect.DeepEqual(user,newUser) {
        fmt.Println(newUser)
    }else{
        fmt.Println(user)
        fmt.Println(newUser)
        t.Error("Cannot marshal and unmarshal User struct")
    }
    dUser := *user
    fmt.Println(dUser)
}
```

By my reading of the documentation this should work! If anyone has a suggestion or workaround I would appreciate it. As an FYI I have tried making the map with the key being both a job and as a pointer to the job with the same results.

Comment: JSON keys MUST be strings, you can have `*Job` implement the json.Unmarshaler and json.Marshaler to make things work, otherwise follow the spec and use strings.

Comment: See https://www.json.org/json-en.html for more insight.

Comment: To correct my previous comment, for [marshaling](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) you need to have `*Job` implement `encoding.TextMarshaler`, for [unmarshaling](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) `*Job` can either implement `json.Unmarshaler` or `encoding.TextUnmarshaler`.